# django very simple login or signup code but is_valid always return false

Tags: python, django

my simple code..

view.py

```
@csrf_protect
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): <<===== Always is_valid return false
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/join_ok/')
        else:
            # If is_valid() False then I want see data
            return HttpResponse(form) <<== print data is no problem
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        return render(request, 'join.html', {'form': form})
```

join.html

```
<h2>Join</h2>
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="join" />
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

is_valid() always return False

Very basic code.

I just want to test login.

But there was a problem in the very basic part.

Comment: Try `print(form.errors)`. That should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Even better, return the errors in the template so that the user can see what was wrong.

Comment: thanks. I checked print(form.errors). I did not have enough skills to understand Django's model structure.